# Use of Bigdecimal while validation epoch expoential timestamp

Tags: java, bigdecimal, numberformatexception, exponent

I have some phone records in which epoch time is coming in exponential format like `1467.738871E9`. I need to validate those records in which number is not in proper format and drop those records.Right now, I am using big decimal,but I have heard that `bigdecimal` is slow and takes more space. Since I have million of records to be validated,is there any other way to validate time which is more space and time efficient.

Code:

```
try {
    new BigDecimal(data).toBigInteger();
} catch (NumberFormatException n) {
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: Since your code is working (although inefficiently), you might want to ask this question on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I am not reviweing it,I am asking if there is any other efficient way to do it.

Comment: The folks at codereview do not only deal with best practice and coding standards, they could review your piece of code with efficiency in mind. Now I'm not saying you won't obtain an answer here, nor did I vote to close your answer, I'm just saying this is an alternative.

Comment: Sure will consider your suggestion next time,Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me. Are you saying that any number in that column that is given in exponential notation is invalid? If so, why not just look for the letter "E" in the string? By the way, your existing code won't throw an exception because exponential notation is just fine for BigDecimal.

Comment: @Klitos                                                                                                                 valid:
1.467983982E9,
1.468119771E9,
1467858808E9,
1.468119771E11,
1468119771E11

invalid:
1.46A802215E9,
null,
4.1B46A802215E9,ABCF456E9

Comment: If it is only about validity, the "rules" are the same for `double`, so you could just as well use that. It could be faster. No need to convert to integer either.